# How do I get a list of the gsutil URIs of all the images in a folder in google cloud storage bucket?

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, export-to-csv

i have a bucket in which i have multiple folders. these folders further have images stored in them. i want to make a csv with the gsutil URIs of all these images. How can I do that?

I could not find a way to get the gsutil URIs of all images at once.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **-R** parameter and it will go thru all folders:
`gsutil ls -R gs://bucket-name`
and then you can use **grep -v :$** to discard folders

Comment: my bucket has folders(the name of the folder is the label of the image) which has 1000s of images inside. is there a way to directly make a csv file with the gcs uri and the label for the entire bucket?